# Orbit camera redirection in threejs

Tags: camera, three.js

I have a problem about camera redirection, unsolved for a long time. Briefly, I have a camera whose up vector is always `(0,1,0)`. I want to move camera's position while keeping a certain 3D point appearing in the same position of the screen.

For example, let `P` be the camera's position, `T` be the camera's lookat, and `F` be the point appearing in `(x,y)` of the screen. Now `P` is changed to `P'` (camera's new position); in order to make `F` still appear in `(x,y)` of the screen, `T` must be changed.

Question is, what is the new value of `T`?

I believe the problem needs a lot of math. Tell me if you have any idea. Thanks greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the object hierarchy instead of applying math to the camera.

```
var cNull = new THREE.Object3D();
var camera == new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
cNull.add(camera);
scene.add(cNull);
```

If you do this, then you can turn the camera to a single angle and the just use your point F(x,y,z) as the `.lookAt()` point for `cNull`. `cNull` will aim its center at `F` and the angular offset of the camera within `cNull`'s coordinate system will keep that `F` point in a constant screen location.

Comment: Thanks @bjorke! Your hierarchy idea is great. Then the camera is fixed at (0,0,0). But how to compute "the angular offset" so that F remains in the same  position of the screen?

Comment: that will depend upon the camera FieldOfView and your screen ressolution -- THREE uses a vertical field of view, so to solve just for the y portion, consider (psuedocode here...)

Comment: (grr, StackOverflow typing rules vs real typing...)

That depends on screen resolution, how F is defined, and the camera FOV. Basically it's just a scaled trig problem from there,.... as a hint remember that FOV is the verical axis in THREE. So IIRC, if 

 `g = tan(FOV/2)*(halfPixelHeight);`

then the new angle for a 2D y part of F is going to be

 `atan((y-halfPixelHeight)/g);`

repeat for X based on the aspect ratio of your screen

 `atan((x-halfPixelWidth)/g);`